Putting a clipped image at the bottom of a page with tikz
I would like to put a clipped image at the bottom of a page using tikz. I can put an unclipped image at the bottom of the page using:
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, inner sep=0pt]     
    \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) 
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};     
\end{tikzpicture}


Which is good. I would also like to clip out the upper left-hand corner of the image. I've tried:
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, inner sep=0pt]
    \clip (0\paperwidth,0\paperwidth) -- (0\paperwidth,.4\paperwidth) -- (1\paperwidth,.78\paperwidth) -- (1\paperwidth,0\paperwidth) -- (0\paperwidth,0\paperwidth); 
    \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) 
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};     
\end{tikzpicture}

This makes the image not show up at all. I can make the clipped image show up by removing the [remember picture, overlay, inner sep=0pt] options:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0\paperwidth,0\paperwidth) -- (0\paperwidth,.4\paperwidth) -- (1\paperwidth,.78\paperwidth) -- (1\paperwidth,0\paperwidth) -- (0\paperwidth,0\paperwidth); 
    \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) 
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};     
\end{tikzpicture}

but it is shifted up and to the right on the page. I've introducing offsets using xshift and yshift, but seems to move the image inside of a window that stays in the same place. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I tried to search for answers, but I was unsuccessful. Thanks for your time!

Welcome. // Please make sure your codes do compile. I.e. make them start with \documentclassetc. and end with \end{document}. Thank you. // Did you try clipping a real picture? Not sure if you can clip the example-pics. // Also width=\paperwidth might be a problem, as it will scale its height, too ...
